# Using task parallel library (TPL) for polling

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, polling

I am new in C# and I have a device (peripheral) which I need to poll through serial/USB from a C# console application. Though the code below apparently does not throw any exceptions (errors), nor it executes the polling. What could be happening ? Thanks.

The console output is:

```
Here goes...
t1: System.Threading.Tasks.Task
```

PD. From debugging, I have the impression the **while(true) {...}** block is not ran.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using T1NET;

namespace ValController
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            T1NET.comm Device = new T1NET.comm();
            bool devfound = true;
            Device.Port = new T1NET.COM_port();
            Device.Port.RtsEnable = false;
            Device.HandlePort = true;
            Device.Port.BaudRate = 9600;
            Device.Port.PortName = "COM4";
            Device.Device = T1NET.Device.Valid;
            Device.Port.ReadTimeout = 100;

            if (devfound)
            {
                BV_Device.HandlePort = true;
                Console.WriteLine("here goes...");
                var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        System.Threading.Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
                        T1NET.Answer answer = Device.RunCommand(T1NET.T1NETCommand.Poll);
                        Console.WriteLine("answer:" + answer);
                    }
                });

                Console.WriteLine("t1: " + t1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way that `while` is not executing is if the task never starts (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010131/task-factory-startnew-not-executing-the-task-when-deployed). If that's not the case try putting a break just before your `answer = ...` statement inside your while loop, does it get hit more than once? It is possible that your task awaits an answer indefinitely upon first execution.

Comment: Wait... I just realized that you start an async task and then the program ends. Try waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks but it behaves kind of in the same way.

Comment: Try adding `t1.Wait()` right before the end of your `if (devfound)` block

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! it's working the loop... The only thing that seems not to be working is the Polling line.

Comment: @ekremer Just a note regarding that - it might very well be that the device you're working with isn't safe to be used from multiple threads. Try opening the device in the background task instead of your main thread and keeping it there as a local. Also, I don't think you know what `BeginCriticalRegion` does and how it's supposed to be used. Just get rid of that line.

Comment: **Hi Luaan**, Thanks for your insights ! I already removed the **BeginCriticalRegion** line and as you expected it made no difference at all. Regarding your first comment about not opening the device in the **main thread**, I would greatly appreciate it if you could shed a light on how to do so.

Comment: Hi Luaan: regarding your comment, I thought I was running this parallel process in another thread different from that of the **main**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample, you started a new asynchronous task, while at the same time your application continues its execution to the end of the `Main` method and suddenly exits before your new task even has a chance of executing its content (in your case, the `while loop`).

You need to wait for your task to complete (or in your case, execute until you kill it). Try structuring your code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //// Your initialization code

   if (devfound)
   {
        //// Device found, prepare for task
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //// Task body
        });

        t1.Wait();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do async programming, and you start a separate task to perform actions while you do other things, then there ought be some place in time where you wait for results from the other task.

Officially you don't know when the other task will start, unless you start fiddling with priorities and stuff. It's up to the operating system to decide after which of your statements the other task starts. So after some processing of yourself you are never certain whether the other task is already started and what it has done, unless you start waiting for some sign of life of the other task.

You can check for the status of the other task, but then you only know whether it started running, maybe it only has performed the first statement. You'll never certain when it will do the next statements.

Proper ways to know about the status of the other task:
 - Wait for it to finish. Useful if you only need the result
 - Wait for some semaphores / events / etc. to be signalled. Useful if you need to be kept informed about the others task progress

Comment: **Hi Harald**, thanks for your comments. I will keep them in mind as I go progressing in this project.