# Task or Thread not working/running when hosted to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task

So I am trying to send email as notification to user and I want it to run `asynchronously`. Initially I implemented with `Task.Factory.StartNew` as below:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { _notify.NotifyUser(params); });
```

`NotifyUser` is a `void method` which actually sends email to the user.

But it was never executing the method. I have placed a `log message` inside `NotifyUser` method, which was never getting logged.

I followed **[`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010131/task-factory-startnew-not-executing-the-task-when-deployed)** and came to know that

> Sometimes this kind of behaviour is an indication of an overloaded ThreadPool. Seeing as these are long running/blocking tasks, they should not be scheduled to run in the ThreadPool, which is where Task.Factory.StartNew will be sending them using the default TaskScheduler

and so I followed what was suggested there which is as below:

```
ThreadStart action=()=>{
    _notify.NotifyUser(params);
};
Thread thread=new Thread(action){IsBackground=true};
thread.Start();
```

Found no luck with the above approach too. Again I followed one more approach which even did not work.

```
Task task = new Task(() => {
     _notify.NotifyUser(params); 
});
task.RunSynchronously(); //or task.Start();
```

Is there any other way I can run this task of sending email? I've heard about `async await` but I read that it will not be used on `void methods`. Can someone let me know what would be the best approach here?

---

**Update**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(t =>
{
   _notify.NotifyUser(params); 
});
```

so that it will execute this method when the thread is available. But still no luck here.

**Actual Code**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddEditUser(UVModel model)
{
    if (HasPermission())
    {
         string message = string.Empty;
         bool success = false;
         string returnUrl = string.Empty;
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             using (_db = new EFDB())
             {
                   //fill user model
                   _db.Entry(user).State = state;
                   _db.SaveChanges();
                   _notify = new SendNotification();
                   _notify.NotifyUser(params); //This has to be asynchronous
                   success = true;
                   returnUrl = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", null, HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Url.Host);
                   message="success";
             }
          }
          else
                message = "Server side validation failed!";
          return Json(new { result = success, message = message, redirectUrl = returnUrl }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
          return Json(new { result = false, message = "You do not have permission to perform this action!", redirectUrl = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**SendNotification.cs**

```
public void NotifyUser(Parameter params)
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
            _db = new EFDB();
            mail.To.Add(params.toAddress);
            mail.From = params.from;

            mail.Subject = params.subject;
            mail.Body = params.body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "some smtp host";
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "pwd");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException se)
            {
                LogError.LogMessage("SmtpFailedRecipientException Exception - " + se.Message.ToString(), context);
            }
            catch (SmtpException se)
            {
                LogError.LogMessage("SmtpException - " + se.Message.ToString(), context);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you showed us located in your project ? Is it inside of controller action method or somewhere else ?

Comment: @Fabjan.. Yes.. It is in controller action method.

Comment: First of all change tag 'C# 4.0' to *.NET Framework* 4.0 as it's confusing.  I removed my answer because in .NET 4.0 it's not possible to use `async await` or `Task.Run()` (both introduced in version 4.5)  On .NET 4.0 you seem to try all options that i can think of. The call on `Task.Factory.StartNew()` should be sufficient to start a new Task presuming that there are some *available threads* in a thread pool.

Comment: @Fabjan Sorry.. Even I got confused with the tags... Yea.. All options I've tried but none worked.. May be I am left with not other option except the one Stephen provided.. But again am facing issue as I mentioned as comment in his answer//

Answer (score 1):

[You should never use `StartNew` unless you're doing dynamic task-based parallelism](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). I explain why on my blog in excruciating detail.

Assuming that you're running on ASP.NET, you should use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. I suspect that you're seeing an exception from your delegate, and QBWI will log any exceptions to the event log.

Comment: Stephen.. Definitely I'll try this n let you know if am able to get what I intend to..

Comment: What is the namespace for this `HostingEnvironment.QueuBackgroundWorkItem`.. I used `System.Web.Hosting` but its not showing `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` under it..

Comment: It was introduced only in .Net Framework 4.5.2  ([link to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx))